# Removing Div tag when screen is at a certain size using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I wanted to know using jQuery or javascript can I remove a certain div tag so that its not displayed at all when the screen gets to a certain size lets say 500px.

Comment: Yes you can, but you'd have to post your code as well if you want help from others ;)

Comment: I'll give all your answer a go thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Sorry I didn't post any code I was looking so a starting point which I should have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `matchMedia` Javascript API, which has a **very** good support across browsers nowadays.

For instance:

```
var width = window.matchMedia('screen and (width: 500px)');
```

`matchMedia` will return a `MediaQueryList` object, which among other things contains a `matches` boolean that indicates if the passed in *media query* currently matches or not.

The *great* thing about those `MediaQueryList` objects is, that they provide methods to *add* and *remove* listeners, when this state changes.

For instance:

```
width.addListener(function( mql ) {
    if( mql.matches ) {
        // yes, the device screen width is now 500 pixels
    } else {
       // no, the width is below 500 pixels
    }
});
```

Comment: But theres is not full cross browser support yet.

Comment: @Bernhard: its basically supported by all current browsers.

Comment: Ok. well all current browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this in jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
       if($(window).width()==500)
         $('div').hide();
       else
         $('div').show();
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

    div.whatever { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: I have tried this I just wanted to try a javascript or jQuery solution for a change. Thanks tho for getting back to me so quickly!